# How to change default Toolbar title text from @string/app_name to "", but only changing styles.xml?

Tags: android, styles, toolbar, title

I have an app with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

In some activities I add the **ToolBar** in **xml** manually that contains **@string/app_name** title text by default.
I know that I can call **setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)** or something like that, but it does not suit me.
I need to other way like changing something in **AppTheme** so the title text will be changed through all app by default.
**How to do that?**

Toolbar that I added:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_default_nav_icon_white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new layout file and adding the Toolbar code in that.
See below this is the layout_app_bar.xml
Where you can specify the title of toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
app:title="WhateverName"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppbarTitle"
app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Then in you activities you can include the layout file just like any other tag. you can use this single layout file of toolbar in all activities.

```
<LinearLayout>
<include
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    layout="@layout/layout_app_bar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I Hope it helped you.
Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried that way. But problem is if I set 'title' attribute in ToolBar in xml to "" (empty string), android actually instead of empty string sets @string/app_name. Weird behaviour.